# How to turn my computer into a webserver and use a Java webapp created using Netbeans

Tags: java, webserver

I created a Java web application using Netbeans, I only got a .war file after clicking on build and I don't know whats the next step, how can I become a server and allow my friends to use this .war file or app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an application server like [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/), or [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) to deploy your application. Each one has its advantages and disadvantages and also different configuration options.

Some application servers can be embedded in your application, or can be used standalone and just drop your .war in them.

Comment: When I created the app in Netbeans I used GlassFish, that's all I know, I used as well JavaDB for database, which comes along with Netbeans, the application is working perfectly and I clicked on BUILD and I got that .war file, I just don't know what to do now, I just want to try this app by making my computer a server, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: When you run it in GlassFish from within Netbeans, it's just a matter of passing the URL to a friend so he can use it. If you want it available through Internet (not just LAN), you might need to open the ports in your firewall. If your application is something serious, you might want to consider web hosting as Code-Guru suggests in his answer.

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions are noob, when I run my application, it runs in the browser as http://localhost:8080/Chat/ , what would be the URL if I want to access it from another computer ?

Comment: It would be `http://<your-local-ip-address>:8080/Chat` (e.g. `http://192.168.1.1:8080/Chat`)

Comment: If I want internet access, It should be the public IP right? and port 80 or 8080? THANK YOU MAN YOU ARE MY SAVIOUR

Comment: Right, use your public IP then. You can configure GlassFish to run on either port, just make sure is open in your firewall.

Comment: @AliBassam Noob questions are always welcome here! We just ask that you show that you are making some effort to learn this stuff and not asking to be spoon-fed. Your comments to this answer demonstrate that you are doing what you can. These kinds of details would have been very helpful as part of your original question. Good luck learning Java! And come back with more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider finding a free web hosting service that supports Java EE. This would be much easier and safer than trying to set up a secure web server on your own machine.